# Object referencing across projects in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, scaffolding

I had a solution that contained two projects, one for the web layer that also contained the models, and another for a Windows forms project that did some other "stuff".  The forms project referenced the web project, and all was fine up until I needed to reference something from the web project in the forms project, which I could not do for circular reference reasons.

So I created a new solution, put the data layer in one project and the web layer in another, so later on I could add the third project, and put in the references I need.  Now when I run the web project, I get the following error;

[image]

So I understand that the web project is struggling to find my namespace from the data project, but I have referenced it, so I don't know what more to do.

***EDIT
This comes as no shock, but it's the view that's the issue.  If I edit my Index.cshtml, it recognises the referenced project.  I tried adding;

```
@using LottoData.Models
```

and intellisense completed as I typed.  However, when I run it now, I get;

[image]

Help!

Comment: Do you mean C# instead of C?

Comment: Other than referencing it, did you write a `using` statement ?

Comment: Yes, I meant C#, and yes, I put in a using statement.  Both projects compile fine, it's just at runtime it falls over.

Comment: @SkinnyPete63 try doing a `clean` if that doesn't work, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders

Comment: Deleted the bin and obj folders, cleaned the solution, rebuilt both projects, same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my bad.  I forgot to change the output type for the data project to "Class Library", it was still set to "Console Program".  Changed that, removed and re-added the reference, cleaned and rebuilt and it works fine now. Thanks @David and @Armand for your input.